# Difference between initialization of array with two dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, array-initialization

In my JPanel I am using tablelayout.jar Oracle library (have a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html)) and so, generally, I have to do the following:

```
private double[][] size = {
        {30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30},
        {30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30}
};
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));
```

where "30" is the dimension respectively for cos and rows. In this case we wanted square cells. So I can do, for example,:

```
p.add(new JButton(), "1,4" /*"col,row"*/);
```

We thought that declaring that "size" matrix like that was not good to do and so we changed the initialization like the following:

```
size = new double[Constants.GUI_ROWS][Constants.GUI_COLS];
for (int i=0; i<Constants.GUI_COLS-1; i++) 
  for (int j=0; j<Constants.GUI_ROWS-1; j++)
    size[i][j] = 30;
```

where

```
Constants.GUI_COLS = 19 ({30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30})
```

and

```
Constants.GUI_ROWS = 17 ({30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30})
```

but this does not work. When we try to add something to the JPanel then nothing is shown. It works only if we write the first initialization by hand. Why this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `Constants.GUI_COLS` rather than `Constants.GUI_COLS-1` in `for ` loop condition

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you sure that generated array is equivalent to hardcoded one? Also, you should post your constants.

Comment: I think that the problem is what you say...hardcoded arrays are different from generated ones...

Comment: well, unlike me, you can actually check it. Just output `Arrays.deepToString(size)` somewhere.

Comment: Hardcoded array has **two** rows: the first with 19 elements and the second with 17 elements. Generated array supposed to have **19** rows: 17 elements each. It's not clear what are you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the same as you did by hand you can use

```
double size[][];
size = new double[2][];
size[0]=new double[19];
size[1]=new double[17];
for (int i=0; i<19; i++)
    size[0][i] = 30;

for (int i=0; i<17; i++)
    size[1][i] = 30;
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it'a clearer! I made a mistake because I thought that the two initializations were the same thing :(

Answer (score 1):

You got the loop conditions off by one. Should be :

```
for (int i=0; i<Constants.GUI_COLS; i++) 
  for (int j=0; j<Constants.GUI_ROWS; j++)
    size[i][j] = 30;
```

Note that if this call

```
p.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));
```

comes before this call :

```
size = new double[Constants.GUI_ROWS][Constants.GUI_COLS];
```

The old array referred by `size` will be used by the `TableLayout`.

Comment: ok...maybe I made a mistake in writing the code but the problem is not that...even if I do what you've written the problem remains. Nothing is shown. I think that there is a different representation of the matrix according to the initialization...

Comment: @LoryLory The question is whether you call `p.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));` before or after the loops that initialize the 2D array.

Comment: of course I call p.setLayout(new TableLayout(size)); AFTER for loops initializations